# Cannot presign URL for years?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

Signature Version 4 is maximum for a week. In Python I did:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                         aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                         config=botocore.client.Config(signature_version='s3')
                         )

    return s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
        'get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket_name,
            'Key': key
        },
        ExpiresIn=400000000)  # this is a max: ~ten years
```

But for Go I found only [func (*Request) Presign](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/request/request.go#L273):

```
req, _ := s3Client.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
    Key:    &key,
})
tenYears := time.Now().AddDate(10, 0, 0).Sub(time.Now())
url, err := req.Presign(tenYears)
```

HTTP response for such URL is:
`AuthorizationQueryParametersError: X-Amz-Expires must be less than a week (in seconds); that is, the given X-Amz-Expires must be less than 604800 seconds.`

No way to presign URL in Go using AWS SDK for years?

Comment: Python version probably silently truncates at the max as well.

Comment: You stated "Signature Version 4 is maximum for a week". That matches the error you're receiving. So, it would seem the maximum is one week.

Comment: What is your use-case for requiring long-lived pre-signed URLs? We might be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I need to have a podcast feed with audio links to a private S3. Alternative solution is to have intermediate "directory" with long random name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pre-sign URL for longer than a week, then your use case for pre-signed URLs is not valid. [According to the spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) it is really just one week.

Pre-signed URLs are often used to serve content from S3 to authenticated users only.

Comment: If you'd like to expand this answer, it is worth noting that pre-signed URLs using Signature Version 2 did support extremely long expirations, but Sig V2 only works only in older regions and [S3 support for Sig V2 will be discontinued in 2019](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/auth-request-sig-v2.html).  All the SDKs now use Signature V4 and you're quite correct -- the max is 1 week.  [CloudFront signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) support much longer expiration and CloudFront can be integrated with S3.